# jQuery ui tabs heightStyle: auto not working - getting height from wrong tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I'm using jQuery UI tabs and as per the documentation have set heightStyle: "auto" to make all tabs as high as the tallest one.

This is the code I'm using to initialise the tabs:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    heightStyle: "auto",
    hide: { effect: "drop", duration: 300 }
});
```

However it's not setting the tab height to the tallest one, and seem to be using heights from different tabs on different pages.

On [this](http://chevrolet.gmtemplate.co.za/new-vehicles/trailblazer/) page the tallest tab is the first one, 'Model Overview' however it's setting the height to the 'Gallery' tab.

On [this](http://chevrolet.gmtemplate.co.za/new-vehicles/utility/) page the tallest one is 'Model Specs' and now it seems to be setting the height to 'Model Overview'.

I've Googled for hours already and I can't figure it out, please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem today (about 1 year later than you) and I noticed that one reason could be that you are changing tabs' contents after calling `tabs()`.

For example, I had to change this:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({heightStyle: "auto"});
codeThatBuildsTabsContents();
```

To this:

```
codeThatBuildsTabsContents();
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({heightStyle: "auto"});
```

Furthermore, if you want to change the contents of any tab, you will have to refresh the tabs:

```
codeThatAltersTabsContents();
$( "#tabs" ).tabs('refresh');
```